# Firebase pubsub function exits before the function is done running

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have written a function that does a lot of asynchronous work, and it takes anywhere between 1-2 minutes to complete. When I deploy this as a Firebase Cloud Function, it works when attached to an http trigger, but is not working in a scheduled pubsub function. In the pubsub version, it exits extremely quickly and my function does not get close to finishing. This is the kind of message I see in the logs after it runs: `Function execution took 114 ms, finished with status: 'ok'` and I can also verify that the work it's supposed to do is never completed.

Here is what my code looks like for the http trigger:

```
export const updatePages = functions
  .runWith(runtimeOpts)
  .https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    functions.logger.info('Hello logs!', { structuredData: true });
    await generateProductList('pubsub', request, response);
  });
```

and the pubsub version:

```
export const updatePagesPubSub = functions
  .runWith(runtimeOpts)
  .pubsub.schedule('0 0,12 * * *')
  .onRun(async (context) => {
    await generateProductList('pubsub');
    return null;
  });
```

For the pubsub, I've tried several different versions of return statements, such as:

```
return generateProductList('pubsub')
```

and also not returning anything and just calling `generateProductList` and `await generateProductList` but none of these have changed the behavior.

A note on the `generateProductsList` function: The first argument it receives is the name of the Firestore document to write too. The second and third arguments are the `request` and `response` from function.https.onRequest. If these two values are provided, then I send a response after all of the function's work is done:

```
if (response) response.send('Hello from Firebase!');
```

If these two arguements are not provided, then the they default to `false` and nothing extra happens (but the rest of the function previous to this runs exactly the same). Here is what the generateProductList function declaration looks like:

```
export const generateProductList = async (
  documentName: string,
  request: functions.https.Request | false = false,
  response: functions.Response<any> | false = false
) => {...}
```

Also just to note, for the http trigger, I call `response()` after the work finishes, and this works fine. The function always waits until completion. How can I get the pubsub function to complete the work before exiting?

Comment: In order to help you we  need to see the code of the TWO `generateProductList()` functions, since they seem to have different signatures.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I updated the question to address this and add some more clarity here. Thank you for the recommendation.

Comment: I don’t see any potential problem. You don’t share the code if the `generateProductList` function but if you correctly await the asynchronous tasks in there it should work: the CF should wait that the async work is completed before finishing and potentially shutting down.

Comment: Hi, can you give me an overview of your process with ? Explaining the workflow between Firebase, Cloud Functions and PubSub. So I can try to debug where the issue lies.